# Delete rows from two tables atomically in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

How do I delete rows from different tables atomically?

Table A has a primary key and foreign key into Table B.

Answer (score 6):

The standard solution is to use [ON DELETE CASCADE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) for your constraint.
Search for 'cascade' on that page.

If that is not an option, this SO question may interest you: [In SQL Server 2005, can I do a cascade delete without setting the property on my tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116968/in-sql-server-2005-can-i-do-a-cascade-delete-without-setting-the-property-on-my)